# How to remove PC name from the terminal

Tags: command-line, playonlinux

How to remove the PC name from the terminal
example

```
rahul@rahul-ThinkPad-L480:~$ 
to 
rahul:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vi .bashrc`:

Original:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

change it to ...

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\w\$ '
fi
```

(basically remove the "@\h"  twice.

Make a backup of .bashrc with

```
cp .bashrc .bashrc.old
```

before editing.